# Change several fields in Array

Tags: c#, .net, packet

I have `byte[]` that represent `Packet` for example:

```
byte[] arr = { 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 };
```

Supposed bytes `03 04 05` represent user name field that i want to change (04, 05 is the user and 03 is the length of all this field) after receive value from user for example:

`kinok` that translate into  `107, 108, 110, 111, 107` so the value inside the packet should change into `06, 107, 108, 110, 111, 107`

How can i replace the old value `03 04 05` with the new one `06, 107, 108, 110, 111, 107` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the byte array to a List of byte and do all the changes including inserts there.Then change back.

Details will depend on your situation, e.g. array size and performance issues. The conversions are simple, but not free..

```
    List<byte> bList = arr.ToList();
    // ...do your changes and inserts...
    arr = bList.ToArray<byte>();
```